# Replacing a file whose file name changes every release with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am creating an installer using Inno Setup and I have a file whose name changes every release (because the file name has the version number embedded in it):

```
#define MY_FILE_NAME "file_1.0.0.jar"

[Files]
Source: {#MY_FILE_NAME}; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
```

How would I make my installer remove `file_1.0.0.jar` from the install location when installing `file_2.0.0.jar`?

Comment: There are few ways. You can use `file_*.jar` for the `Source` parameter. Or e.g. pass that file name through the command line. Or e.g. read the version information from that *.jar file if (your) *.jar files supports that.

Comment: Ok, I missed the point of removing, so the last way is nonsense. I hope I've helped you at least with the file mask.

Comment: @TLama Thanks for looking at my question--mainly I'm concerned about how to remove the old file from the `{app}` location, not about selecting which files get embedded in my installer.

Comment: This is one of the arguments for not using versioned filenames/IDs unless multiple versions can coexist.

Comment: @Deanna In many cases I agree with you, but during development with rapid iteration I need to identify file versions at a glance, and having the version in the filename is an effective way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an `[InstallDelete]` section which seems to do the trick:

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{app}\file_*.jar"
```